# Airflow DAG Execution Issues : Dependencies Blocking Task From Getting Scheduled

Tags: airflow, execution, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am very new to Airflow and this is my first DAG. Currently I am facing an issue while trying to execute the DAG. When I trigger the DAG, it shows as "running", but the first task itself did not get executed, it did not even start. On clicking the **Task Instance Details**, it shows as below.

**Dependencies Blocking Task From Getting Scheduled**
**Dependency    ****Reason**
Task Instance State : Task is in the 'queued' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.

There are no other dependencies and no other runs that are in progress.
In the script, Start date is set as: 'start_date': datetime(2023, 1, 1) and schedule_interval=None.

Requesting any help/inputs on this issue. Thanks in advance.

I checked if any existing runs were there, cleared the state and executed the DAG again, but still same issue is observed.